# Can you see exclusive car models from other platforms when playing cross-platform?

Tags: rocket-league

When playing a cross-platform Rocket League match, is it possible to see the exclusive cars from other platforms, or do those car models get replaced with a non-exclusive model (such as Octane) locally?

For example, let's say I'm playing on Xbox and my opponent is playing on Switch.  If my opponent is using the exclusive Mario/Luigi car model, will I see that car on my end or will it get swapped out for a non-exclusive model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/8aul1w/consoleexclusive_cars_dont_show_on_other_platforms/), it looks like the answer is no you do not see the exclusive cars across the platforms.  [Another site](https://gamedummy.com/rocketgate/) shows a .GIF illustrating between PC and a Nintendo Switch that the exclusive car gets replaced by an Octane on the PC side. It also has a link to a full YouTube video as well: